# Date format in an Oracle stored procedure called from Java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am trying to use an Oracle stored procedure to update a database table. I am calling the procedure from a Java program. I want my procedure to accept dates in the format '01-01-2015' but for some reason my procedure will only accept a date if it is formatted as '01-JAN-2015'.

My stored procedure:

```
    DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateAward
(
    p_award_id IN awards.award_id%TYPE,
    p_award_date IN awards.award_date%TYPE,
    p_total_amount IN awards.total_amount%TYPE,
    p_number_sales IN awards.number_sales%TYPE,
    p_emp_id IN awards.emp_id%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE awards
SET award_date = to_date(p_award_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
total_amount = p_total_amount,
number_sales = p_number_sales,
emp_id = p_emp_id
WHERE award_id = p_award_id;

COMMIT;
END;
/
```

The java code that calls it:

```
public boolean updateByID(Connection conn, String strVar, int[] intVar, double doubleVar)
    {
        System.out.println(strVar);
        System.out.println(doubleVar);
        System.out.println(intVar[0]);
        System.out.println(intVar[1]);
        System.out.println(intVar[2]);
        try
        {
            String query = "{call updateAward(?,?,?,?,?)}";
            CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query);

                stmt.setInt(1,intVar[0]);
                stmt.setString(2, strVar);
                stmt.setDouble(3, doubleVar);
                stmt.setInt(4, intVar[1]);
                stmt.setInt(5, intVar[2]);

                stmt.executeUpdate();
                return true;
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The console print out of the variables being passed:

```
12-12-2012
65165.2
21
22
3
```

The error itself:

```
KORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Every solution that I have found has been to put the date format in the procedure. I believe I have done it with

```
award_date = to_date(p_award_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
```

Have I written it incorrectly? Can someone please help?

Comment: What data type is `awards.award_date`? Presumably it's already a date, so you're doing an implicit conversion.

Comment: Yes it is a date. Is the to_date conflicting with this in some way?

Comment: The line `SET award_date = to_date(p_award_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')` makes no sense as both `award_date` and `p_award_date` are of the same type, a DATE type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are passing a String:

```
stmt.setString(2, strVar);
```

And you are parsing a String:

```
award_date = to_date(p_award_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

But **you are expecting a Date in your custom type**, and that is where the conversion fails. Change that to VARCHAR (or VARCHAR2) and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a string to a procedure that's expecting an Oracle date argument, via `setString()`. That means Oracle has to do an implicit conversion of the string to a date as part of the call, using the session/locale NLS_DATE_FORMAT, before you reach your `to_date()` call.

You could change your procedure argument type from `awards.award_date%TYPE` to `varchar2`, and still do the explicit conversion inside the procedure. Or you can leave the procedure signature as it is and pass the correct data type by converting it on the Java side, e.g.:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
cStmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(sdf.parse(strVar).getTime()));
```

And as `p_date` is already a date, you should not call `to_date()` on that, as it will do an implicit conversion back to a string (using NLS_DATE_FORMAT again) and then try to explicitly convert that back to a date using the format model you supplied, which is also likely to give a similar error. Simplify that to just:

```
SET award_date = p_award_date,
```